# Set marker visible with knockout JS ko.utils.arrayFilter

Tags: google-maps, knockout.js

Hello guys I am trying to create an app that sets the appropriate markers visible when a knockout search is being done.

Basically the app is.
When someone does a search the list that is bellow it, filters the list and makes only the markers that are associated with the filter list visible on the map.
I have created a ko.utils.arrayFilter and I am trying to set only the item.marker.setVisible(true)

My Github link is https://github.com/Aimpotis/map3

Thank you again and much respect to the community it is helping me learn a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is to set the visibility of the marker to match whether it is found:

```
if (!filter) {
  // this is new
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.listLoc(), function (item) {
    item.marker.setVisible(true);
  });
  return self.listLoc();
} else {
  return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.listLoc(), function(item) {
    var result = (item.title.toLowerCase().search(filter) >= 0)
    item.marker.setVisible(result); // this is a new line
    return result;
  });
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dy70fe16/1/).

Note: unless you're supporting particularly old browsers, you can use the [Array filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) rather than Knockout's `arrayFilter` util, and [`.foreach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of `arrayForEach`.

Comment: I have no words to thank you man, You can not imagine how much you helped me with this. Respect to you and all the people who help out.

Comment: Only one issue if I make a filter and then delete it, then it does not reset the markers to make them all visible.

Comment: Right. Gotta set the visibility in the branch that returns the whole list, too. Update answer and fiddle.

Comment: You are simply the best

Comment: Hello can I ask you an other question about infowindows

Comment: You don't have to just ask me. You can post a question.

Comment: If you go step by step in explaining that function @RoyJ

Comment: @Elhaw The code I used was the body of a `computed` in the original poster's github, but which I see has now been deleted from it. [It is here](https://github.com/Aimpotis/map3/commit/e3baa7a13fac0e7598f17c961551b0518faf9abf#diff-2ba34fedf3f48f179642995bd236349f). I just added code to update the marker visibility to keep it in sync with the data.