# How do I show the results of a filtered list using Knockout.Js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am building an app that takes a list of restaurants and displays them on a Google Map. I also display this list so the user can see the names of the restaurants.

I want to filter the list using Knockout.js so that when someone starts typing the name of the restaurant, only the one's that match the query appear.

**HTML + Knockout Bindings**

```
<div>
  <div id="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Filter" data-bind="textInput:query">
  </div>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: restaurants">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var restaurants = [
    {name: 'Chez Simone', location: {lat:48.8603937, lng: 2.3430545}},
    {name: 'Cafe Coutume', location: {lat:48.851599, lng: 2.3162123}},
    {name: 'Café Pinson', location: {lat:48.863732, lng: 2.3631037}},
    {name: 'Sol Semilla', location: {lat:48.8730959, lng: 2.363135900000001}},
    {name: 'Juice Lab Marais', location: {lat:48.8563595, lng: 2.3637123}}
];

//viewModel
var viewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.restaurantList = ko.observableArray(restaurants);

  //Stores user input
  self.query = ko.observable('');

  // Filters through observableArray and filters results using util.arrayFilter();
  self.search = ko.computed(function(){
    var query = this.query().toLowerCase();
    if(!query) {
      return self.restaurantList();
    } else {
      //go through restaurant list and for each restaurant, check if the letters in query
      // appear in restaurant name. If so, display name. else don't.
      var restaurantList = self.restaurantList();
      for(i = 0; i < restaurantList.length; i++){
        var restaurant = restaurantList[i];
        var restaurantName = restaurant.name;
        // check if query letter/s appears in restaurant name
        if(restaurantName.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1){
        // Help! This is where I'm stuck. 
         return restaurantName;
        }
      }
    }
  }, self);
}; // viewModel ends `
```

The logic I have so far works - if I use `console.log(restaurantName)` it prints out only the correct restaurants. I can't get it to appear in the view.

How do I display it in the list view?

Comment: this looks fairly similiar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422066/set-marker-visible-with-knockout-js-ko-utils-arrayfilter  I updated the fiddle to use your locations.  https://jsfiddle.net/dy70fe16/3/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set marker visible with knockout JS ko.utils.arrayFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422066/set-marker-visible-with-knockout-js-ko-utils-arrayfilter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `computed` property `search` should always return an `array` so you can bind the `foreach` to the *filtered* collection.

You already got the first part:

```
if (!query) return self.restaurantList();
```

In other words, if you're not searching, show all restaurants.

You also succeeded to get most of the last part working, except the part where you loop and return.

You'll have to use `restaurantList.filter` (or, as you mention in your comment, `util.arrayFilter`) to create an array of items that match your query.

```
 return self.restaurantList().filter(function(restaurant) {
     return (restaurant.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1)
 });
```

Then, with `foreach: search`, you'll get the snippet below:

```js
var restaurants = [
    {name: 'Chez Simone', location: {lat:48.8603937, lng: 2.3430545}},
    {name: 'Cafe Coutume', location: {lat:48.851599, lng: 2.3162123}},
    {name: 'Café Pinson', location: {lat:48.863732, lng: 2.3631037}},
    {name: 'Sol Semilla', location: {lat:48.8730959, lng: 2.363135900000001}},
    {name: 'Juice Lab Marais', location: {lat:48.8563595, lng: 2.3637123}}
];

//viewModel
var viewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.restaurantList = ko.observableArray(restaurants);

  //Stores user input
  self.query = ko.observable('');

  self.search = ko.computed(function(){
    var query = this.query().toLowerCase();
    if(!query) {
      return self.restaurantList();
    } else {
      var restaurantList = self.restaurantList();
      return restaurantList.filter(function(restaurant) {
        var restaurantName = restaurant.name;
        return (restaurantName.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1)
      });
    }
  }, self);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div id="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Filter" data-bind="textInput:query">
  </div>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: search">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Note that to update any markers in the google maps UI, you'll have to subscribe to `search` and update your map accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it out, but nothing changes when I type something into the input. In other words, the list doesn't filter, it stays the same. Any ideas of why that could be?

Comment: Dus you change the binding to refer to the computed list rather than the original source?

Comment: That was it. I had forgotten to change the foreach to search.